# trying to start a new activity from my pop up menu

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to load a new activity called `Make_a_contact`. The user should click on `id_Admin` on the pop up menu and it should load `Make_a_contact`.

The second menu item `id_User` loads the Toast part just fine.

In my build error I get:

```
Error:(22, 50) error: cannot find symbol variable Make_a_contact
```

Do you know what could be wrong?

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.chris.omgandroid;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
/**
 * Created by Chris on 07/01/2016.
 */
public class PopUpMenuEventHandle extends Activity implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    Context context;
    public PopUpMenuEventHandle(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){

        if(item.getItemId()==R.id.id_Admin)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent (context, Make_a_contact);
            startActivity(intent);
//            Toast.makeText(context, "LoginAdmin has loaded!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//            return true;
        }

        else if(item.getItemId()==R.id.id_User){

            Toast.makeText(context, "LoginUser has loaded!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: not too sure what you mean. It is an activity in my android project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Make_a_contact.class
```

should  like this

Comment: That's probably right answer - don't get build error any more - but now when I start popup menu on phone the app shuts down and I get error in logcat: 1404-1404/com.example. chris.omgandroid E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException at android.content. ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3430)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3388)
at com.example.chris.omgandroid.PopUpMenuEventHandle. onMenuItemClick(PopUpMenuEventHandle.java:23) etc, etc... Any ideas?

Comment: @CHarris, were you able to resolve the null pointer? I'm facing the same and could use suggestions, if any.

Comment: @Nikhil Gupta Are you using a cursor in the next activity? It's a long time ago now but I'm pretty sure that was the problem - yes, fixed for a long time now. I wasn't initializing cursor correctly or not closing it, let me know and I can dig deeper.

Answer (score 3):

The `Intent` expects the `Class` instance of your Activity, which you can access with the `.class` field:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Make_a_contact.class);
```

Just providing the standalone class name `Make_a_contact` is invalid Java in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, +1'd it. I suppose it's only fair I give Zack the correct answer though as you both said the same thing, just he was first.